# Excel: Sum a column in a date range (as indicated in a different column)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following sheet:

[image: Screen Shot of Excel Worksheet]

Column C has dates that an assignment is due, and Column H has estimates of how long each assignment will take. I would like to total the estimated durations for each week.

I put the first day of each week in Column N and the last day in Column O, and used this formula in Column P:

```
=SUMIFS($H$2:$H$98, $C$2:$C$98, ">N2", $C$2:$C$98, "<O2")
```

which seems like it should work, but as you can see all I am getting are 0's in Column P.

Column P is formatted as [h]:mm;@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Below shown method solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:** I've used only required columns.

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get first day of the week the formula in cell F51:

  `=C51-WEEKDAY(C51,2)+1`

**N.B.**

- *In Column C (Due By) dates has year, `2019`.*
- *This formula uses **M**onday as the first day of the week, you can modify it according to popular practice in your zone, like if the week starts form **S**unday then the formula should,*

  `=C51-WEEKDAY(C51,1)+1`
- To get last day of the week the formula in cell H51:

  `=C51+7-WEEKDAY(C51,2)`
- Final formula in cell I51:

  ```
  =SUMIFS($D$51:$D$64, $C$51:$C$64, ">="&F51, $C$51:$C$64, "<="&H51)
  ```

*Applied format in column I is, `[h]:mm;@`*

**N.B.**

- *Your formula has wrong syntax `$C$2:$C$98, ">N2"`, was one of the reasons, and the second was using `>` & `<`, where it should `>=` & `<=`.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @SteveScher ,,, keep asking ☺